# VBA: refer to named ranges in several worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a problem programming in VBA. My workbook contains 20 sheets and each sheet has several named ranges and I use dependent comboboxes. For example, the value of my second combobox depends on the value selected in the first combobox, and the subset of values of the first combobox itself are located in different sheets. How can I refer to all these named ranges without referring to its sheet?

Comment: Names in the same workbook need to be unique and don't need a sheet reference to be used. Just `Range("nameHere")` should take the correct range regardless of which sheet is active.

Comment: @Notus_Panda Note that you can have multiple Ranges with the same name if the scope is "Worksheet".

Comment: @FunThomas I have tried giving a different range the same name in both the same Worksheet and a different Worksheet and both got a Msgbox stating that names should be unique. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You can add Ranges with Scope "Worksheet" only in the name manager, and of course you can have the same name only once per sheet.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I see what you mean now. *Don't* do that then @OP and you won't have an issue with referring to named ranges without sheet references :)

Comment: [Create Dependent Drop-Down Lists](https://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html)

Comment: Why not using the sheet if you have names in the scope of the sheet (one of the big problems in copying sheets :-)
Instead of MyWorkbook.Names("foo")  you use MyWorkSheet.Names("foo").
It's a question of the container of the name.